# How to prove $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{p_k^2+1}{p_k^2-1}}=\frac{5}{2}$?

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, infinite-product

I came across [the following formula due to Ramanujan](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeProducts.html):

$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{p_k^2+1}{p_k^2-1}}=\frac{5}{2}.$$

Can someone show me what the proof of this looks like, or point me to a reference (in English)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

By [Euler's product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_the_Euler_product_formula_for_the_Riemann_zeta_function), for any $s>1$ we have
$$ \zeta(s)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^s} = \prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1} \tag{A}$$
hence
$$ \prod_{p}\frac{p^2+1}{p^2-1} = \prod_p\frac{1-\frac{1}{p^4}}{\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)^2} = \frac{\zeta(2)^2}{\zeta(4)} = \frac{90}{36} = \frac{5}{2}.\tag{B}$$
Similarly, $\prod_{p}\frac{p^4+1}{p^4-1}=\frac{7}{6}$.